# Помогите объяснить смысл некоторых фраз из Фауста

Tags: литература, смысл, поэзия

```
Начало строф, родившихся вчерне.
```

Почему в черне?

```
Чтоб сразу показать липом товар,
Новинку надо ввесть в репертуар.
```

Что значит "липом товар"?

```
Нет четырех, а ловкие проныры,
```

Про каких "четырех" идёт речь?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Вчерне** — это черновые сроки. **Липом** — опечатка: лицом. **Нет четырёх** часов, а проныры уже тут как тут (намного раньше начала спектакля то есть).